# hello guys does someone know how to read a file uploaded by a user in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello Im trying to read a user uploaded file in discord.py does anyone know how I would go about it? I have read different articles on How to handle a file upload from a user in discord py but I could not find anything so im hoping someone can help me find out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it, it checks if an attachment is sent and downloads it.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel)
    author=str(message.author)

    try:
        url = message.attachments[0].url
        if message.attachments[0].url:
            print(f'\nNew attachment recieved from {author}.')
            print(f'Attachment Link: {message.attachments[0].url}\n')

            r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
            file = 'file.txt'
            open(file, 'wb').write(r.content)
    except:
        pass
```